# How to prove $E[e^x]=e^{E[x]+Var[x]/2}$ when $x$ is a centered Gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

$E[]$ is the expectation and $Var[]$ is the variance.

Comment: This is not true. Say, for $\mathbb P(X=\pm 1)=0.5$, l.h.s. is $\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}$, and r.h.s. is $\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: @NCh Thanks. I get this formula from https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/M7%20assignment%20-%2072.pdf, just right under Eq.(7) of its page 3. The formula also appears in the related textbook.

Comment: If $X$ is normally distributed $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then this formula is true. Look at MGF of normal distribution. And there is a huge number of counterexamples for non-normal cases.

Comment: Thanks. I will add the constraint for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the expectation of $e^X$, with $X$ normal $(0 , \sigma^2)$, is:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} e^x \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi \sigma}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\right) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{x - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma}} e^{\sigma^2 / 2} \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{2 \sigma}})^2} dx = e^{\sigma^2/2}
$$

To get the third step, I completed the square $x - \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}$ to a perfect square. For the fourth, I set $\frac{t}{\sqrt 2} = 1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt 2\sigma}$ and simplified using the usual Gaussian integral $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-t^2 / 2}dt = \sqrt{2\pi}$ to conclude.

Of course, if $X$ is not centered, say $X = N(\mu , \sigma^2)$, then you can still carry out a similar thing and conclude that the complete formula is $e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$.